# Decryption of p7b / pkcs7 files in PHP

Tags: php, pkcs#7

I need to decrypt a PKCS7-encrypted file which I get from an API. For the moment, I'm not really clear about this file format, so please apologize if some of my questions may sound stupid.

Am I right that the certificate and the content are both included within the .p7b file, so this file by itself is enough? All PHP functions related to decyprtion (like openssl_pkcs7_read or openssl_pkcs7_decrypt) need a link to a certificate – is this certificate supposed to be a separate file? For the moment, all I get from the API is this one file.

If the .p7b file is enough, how do I get the content with PHP code (not command line, as on the environment I don't have access to it)? Do I need anything else from the provider, e.g. a password?

Thank you, cheers,
Frederik

Comment: For pkcs7 decryption , read [the official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-decrypt.php) please - try the example code on that page and let us know if you still have problems.